# VLC multiple screen video playback with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: vlc

I have a simple script that play a video full screen on a non graphical Raspbian environment on a simple button press.

I'm using the VLC's python binding to achieve this.

Now I want to be able to play a video on 2 screen using the Raspberry Pi 4  HDMIs output but I can't find on the VLC api documentation how to select the video output.

My actual workaround is using omxplayer-sync and 2 Raspberry Pi 3 connected in the same LAN, to play and sync the video but using a single raspberry pi to achieve the same effect would be really nice (also this remove the need of having a local network and the related hardware).

So is there a way to achieve this using the libVLC's binding ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me understand, you want to have multiple VLC instances playing at the same time? I have tried this using Qt framework.

With Qt framework and VLC-Python, I've managed to have two widgets containing different VLC instance. The first widget positioned at x position 0, and the second one at 1920 respectively. 1920 is the starting x position of 2nd monitor.

However, at the time of this writing, this method no longer work, because VLC doesn't allow playing multiple instance on Pi of its latest version.

I believe this will be fixed in the future versions of VLC for Raspbian.

Arnold